# LWC: count amount of checkboxes that are currently checked

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I am trying to get the amount of checkbox that are currently checked on a change handler.
What I have so far:

```
<template for:each={objInfo.todoList} for:item='todoListItem' class="slds-p-top_medium">
    <lightning-input 
          key={todoListItem.fieldName} 
          name={todoListItem.fieldName} 
          label={todoListItem.fieldLabel} 
          type={todoListItem.fieldType} 
          value={todoListItem.value} 
          disabled={todoListItem.disabledRes}
          checked={todoListItem.value}                                                
          onchange={handleTodoChange} >
     </lightning-input>
 </template>
```

and

```
activeCheckboxesCount = 0;

....

handleTodoChange(event) {
           
    if(event.target.checked==true) {
        this.activeCheckboxesCount++;
    } else {
        this.activeCheckboxesCount--;
    }
    
}
```

But instead of starting with 0 I would need to start with the initial value for checked checkboxes (on response). So I am looking for an iteration here. How do I do this?

**UPDATE** in response to user sfdcfox

I think I am still doing something wrong. Not clear which params to use for the query:

```
get activeCheckboxesCount() {
    return [...this.template.querySelectorAll('todoListItem')]
        .filter((todoListItem) => todoListItem.checked)
        .length
}
```

Comment: assuming you update/store a property in your `objInfo.todoList` , it would be much easier to simply count checked items from your array of todo's. If you don't do that already, consider changing approaches, and always updating your array prop and make your ui reactive to changes in your array vs having to handle both separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generically speaking, you can do something like:

```
get activeCheckboxesCount() {
  return [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
    .filter((todoItem) => todoItem.checked)
    .length
}
```

Where we get all todo items, filter those that are checked, and return the length. This works on demand, so you can just:

```
let activeCount = this.activeCheckboxesCount
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I think I am still doing something wrong. Not clear which params to use for the query (especially c-todo-item is absolutly unclear to me, where this comes from). I have updated my question above

Comment: @JonSnow I thought you had two components, like `c-todo` and `c-todo-item`. You can query by the element name, or you could add a CSS class or something else to query by. You can read more about [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), just remember in LWC you use `this.template` instead of `document`.

Answer (score 2):

your code looks fine.
But are we calling a DOM query on All lightning inputs? This includes all input types defined in standard HTML5. It would be a good practice to narrow the DOM search filter.

```
return Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input[type="toggle"])).filter(todoListItem=>{
    return todoListItem.value==true              // or todoListItem.checked
 })
```